# ORA-00904 "invalid identifier" but identifier exists in query

Tags: sql, oracle, identifier

I'm working in a fault-reporting Oracle database, trying to get fault information out of it.

The main table I'm querying is Incident, which includes incident information. Each record in Incident may have any number of records in the WorkOrder table (or none) and each record in WorkOrder may have any number of records in the WorkLog table (or none).

What I am trying to do at this point is, for each record in Incident, find the WorkLog with the minimum value in the field MXRONSITE, and, for that worklog, return the MXRONSITE time and the REPORTDATE from the work order. I accomplished this using a MIN subquery, but it turned out that several worklogs could have the same MXRONSITE time, so I was pulling back more records than I wanted. I tried to create a subsubquery for it, but it now says I have an invalid identifier (ORA-00904) for WOL1.WONUM in the WHERE line, even though that identifier is in use elsewhere.

Any help is appreciated. Note that there is other stuff in the query, but the rest of the query works in isolation, and this but doesn't work in the full query or on its own.

```
SELECT    
      WL1.MXRONSITE as "Date_First_Onsite",
      WOL1.REPORTDATE as "Date_First_Onsite_Notified"
FROM Maximo.Incident
LEFT JOIN (Maximo.WorkOrder WOL1
           LEFT JOIN Maximo.Worklog WL1
                  ON WL1.RECORDKEY = WOL1.WONUM) 
       ON WOL1.ORIGRECORDID = Incident.TICKETID 
          AND WOL1.ORIGRECORDCLASS = 'INCIDENT'
WHERE (WL1.WORKLOGID IN 
       (SELECT MIN(WL3.WORKLOGID) 
        FROM (SELECT MIN(WL3.MXRONSITE), WL3.WORKLOGID  
              FROM Maximo.Worklog WL3 WHERE WOL1.WONUM = WL3.RECORDKEY)) 
       or WL1.WORKLOGID is null)
```

To clarify, what I want is:

- For each fault in Incident,
- the earliest MXRONSITE from the Worklog table (if such a value exists),
- For that worklog, information from the associated record from the WorkOrder table.

This is complicated by Incident records having multiple work orders, and work orders having multiple work logs, which may have the same MXRONSITE time.

---

After some trials, I have found an (almost) working solution:

```
WITH WLONSITE as (
SELECT
MIN(WLW.MXRONSITE) as "ONSITE",
WLWOW.ORIGRECORDID as "TICKETID",
WLWOW.WONUM as "WONUM"
FROM
MAXIMO.WORKLOG WLW
INNER JOIN
MAXIMO.WORKORDER WLWOW
ON
WLW.RECORDKEY = WLWOW.WONUM
WHERE
WLWOW.ORIGRECORDCLASS = 'INCIDENT'
GROUP BY 
WLWOW.ORIGRECORDID, WLWOW.WONUM
)

select
incident.ticketid,
wlonsite.onsite,
wlonsite.wonum
from
maximo.incident

LEFT JOIN WLONSITE
ON WLONSITE.TICKETID = Incident.TICKETID

WHERE 
(WLONSITE.ONSITE is null or WLONSITE.ONSITE = (SELECT MIN(WLONSITE.ONSITE) FROM WLONSITE WHERE WLONSITE.TICKETID = Incident.TICKETID AND ROWNUM=1))
AND Incident.AFFECTEDDATE >= TO_DATE ('01/12/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

This however is significantly slower, and also still not quite right, as it turns out a single Incident can have multiple Work Orders with the same ONSITE time (aaargh!).

---

As requested, here is a sample input, and what I want to get from it (apologies for the formatting). Note that while TICKETID and WONUM are primary keys, they are strings rather than integers. WORKLOGID is an integer.

Incident table:
TICKETID / Description / FieldX
1 / WORD1 / S
2 / WORD2 / P
3 / WORDX /
4 /       / Q

Work order table:
WONUM / ORIGRECORDID / REPORTDATE
11 / 1 / 2015-01-01
12 / 2 / 2015-01-01
13 / 2 / 2015-02-04
14 / 3 / 2015-04-05

Worklog table:
WORKLOGID / RECORDKEY / MXRONSITE
101 / 11 / 2015-01-05
102 / 12 / 2015-01-04
103 / 12 /
104 / 12 / 2015-02-05
105 / 13 /

Output:
TICKETID / WONUM / WORKLOGID
1 / 11 / 101
2 / 12 / 102
3 /    /
4 /    /
(Worklog 101 linked to TICKETID 1, has non-null MXRONSITE, and is from work order 11)
(Worklogs 102-105 linked to TICKETID 2, of which 102 has lowest MXRONSITE, and is work order 12)
(No work logs associated with faults 103 or 104, so work order and worklog fields are null)

---

Post Christmas attack!

I have found a solution which works:

The method I found was to use multiple WITH queries, as follows:

```
WLMINL AS (
  SELECT 
  RECORDKEY, MXRONSITE, MIN(WORKLOGID) AS "WORKLOG"
  FROM MAXIMO.WORKLOG
  WHERE WORKLOG.CLASS = 'WORKORDER'
  GROUP BY RECORDKEY, MXRONSITE
),
WLMIND AS (
  SELECT
  RECORDKEY, MIN(MXRONSITE) AS "MXRONSITE"
  FROM MAXIMO.WORKLOG
  WHERE WORKLOG.CLASS = 'WORKORDER'
  GROUP BY RECORDKEY
),
WLMIN AS (
  SELECT
  WLMIND.RECORDKEY AS "WONUM", WLMIND.MXRONSITE AS "ONSITE",   WLMINL.WORKLOG AS "WORKLOGID"
  FROM
  WLMIND
  INNER JOIN
  WLMINL
  ON
  WLMIND.RECORDKEY = WLMINL.RECORDKEY AND WLMIND.MXRONSITE =   WLMINL.MXRONSITE
)
```

Thus for each work order finding the first date, then for each work order and date finding the lowest worklogid, then joining the two tables. This is then repeated at a higher level to find the data by incident.

However this method does not work in a reasonable time, so while it may be suitable for smaller databases it's no good for the behemoths I'm working with.

Comment: Will that not mean it's left joining the incident table directly to the worklog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with `row_number` function:

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ec4f/1)</sup>

```
select ticketid, case when worklogid is not null then reportdate end d1, mxronsite d2
  from (
    select i.ticketid, wo.reportdate, wl.mxronsite, wo.wonum, wl.worklogid,
           row_number() over (partition by i.ticketid 
                                  order by wl.mxronsite, wo.reportdate) rn
      from incident i 
        left join workorder wo on wo.origrecordid = i.ticketid 
                              and wo.origrecordclass = 'INCIDENT'
        left join worklog wl   on wl.recordkey = wo.wonum )
  where rn = 1 order by ticketid
```

Comment: I've had a look at this, and it certainly seems to have potential. I think I need to work a bit on understanding all it does before I can say definitively that this is what I'm after, but it certainly seems a step in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. I'm confused though by the left join to the worklog table, as the join is by fields from a different table rather than directly. I didn't know this was possible, and am a bit confused as to how it works.

Comment: Thinking about this, topic not closed.

Answer (score 0):

When you nest subqueries, you cannot access columns that belong two or more levels higher; in your statement, WL1 is not accessible in the innermost subquery. (There is also a group-by clause missing, btw)

This might work (not exactly sure what output you expect, but try it):

```
SELECT

WL1.MXRONSITE as "Date_First_Onsite",
WOL1.REPORTDATE as "Date_First_Onsite_Notified"

FROM Maximo.Incident

LEFT JOIN (
  Maximo.WorkOrder WOL1
  LEFT JOIN Maximo.Worklog WL1
  ON WL1.RECORDKEY = WOL1.WONUM
) ON WOL1.ORIGRECORDID = Incident.TICKETID 
AND WOL1.ORIGRECORDCLASS = 'INCIDENT'

WHERE WL1.WORKLOGID =
  ( SELECT MIN(WL3.WORKLOGID)
      FROM Maximo.WorkOrder WOL3
      LEFT JOIN Maximo.Worklog WL3
        ON WL3.RECORDKEY = WOL3.WONUM
      WHERE WOL3.ORIGRECORDID = WOL1.ORIGRECORDID
        AND WL3.MXRONSITE IS NOT NULL
  )
  OR WL1.WORKLOGID IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS 
     ( SELECT MIN(WL4.WORKLOGID)
         FROM Maximo.WorkOrder WOL4
         LEFT JOIN Maximo.Worklog WL4
           ON WL4.RECORDKEY = WOL4.WONUM
         WHERE WOL4.ORIGRECORDID = WOL1.ORIGRECORDID
           AND WL4.MXRONSITE IS NOT NULL )
```

Comment: I'm testing this using a particular fault which has about 40 worklogs and two different non-null ONSITE times as well as a null, and your result unfortunately returns the null ONSITE. However, knowing about the limits to subquery access should help me work out a way to pull the correct value.

Comment: maybe `AND WL3.MXRONSITE IS NOT NULL` in the subquery will do the trick?

Comment: Changed my answer, please try again

Comment: That's an improvement, but it now brings back the ONSITE time for each work order, so if a record in the Incident table has multiple work orders it gives extra rows.

Comment: oh well... next attempt

Comment: That then knocks out any records where there is no ONSITE date, or no work order. I've had a go at doing it using a WITH clause (adding to the original question), but that is much much slower, and will be problematic given I'll end up applying this to an incidents table with about a million records.

Answer (score 0):

I may not have the details right on what you're trying to do...  if you have some sample input and desired output, that would be a big help.

That said, I think an analytic function would help a lot, not only in getting the output but in organizing the code.  Here is an example of how the `max` analytic function in a subquery could be used.

Again, the details on the join may be off -- if you can furnish some sample input and output, I'll bet someone can get to where you're trying to go:

```
with wo as (
  select
    wonum, origrecordclass, origrecordid, reportdate,
    max (reportdate) over (partition by origrecordid) as max_date
  from Maximo.workorder
  where origrecordclass = 'INCIDENT'
),
logs as (
  select
    worklogid, mxronsite, recordkey,
    max (mxronsite) over (partition by recordkey) as max_mx
  from Maximo.worklog
)
select
  i.ticketid,
  l.mxronsite as "Date_First_Onsite",
  wo.reportdate as "Date_First_Onsite_Notified"
from
  Maximo.incident i
  left join wo on
    wo.origrecordid = i.ticketid and
    wo.reportdate = wo.max_date
  left join logs l on
    wo.wonum = l.recordkey and
    l.mxronsite = l.max_mx
```

-- edit --

Based on your sample input and desired output, this appears to give the desired result.  It does do somewhat of an explosion in the subquery, but hopefully the efficiency of the analytic functions will dampen that.  They are typically much faster, compared to using group by:

```
with wo_logs as (
  select
    wo.wonum, wo.origrecordclass, wo.origrecordid, wo.reportdate,
    l.worklogid, l.mxronsite, l.recordkey,
    max (reportdate) over (partition by origrecordid) as max_date,
    min (mxronsite) over (partition by recordkey) as min_mx
  from
    Maximo.workorder wo
    left join Maximo.worklog l on wo.wonum = l.recordkey
  where wo.origrecordclass = 'INCIDENT'
)
select
  i.ticketid, wl.wonum, wl.worklogid,
  wl.mxronsite as "Date_First_Onsite",
  wl.reportdate as "Date_First_Onsite_Notified"
from
  Maximo.incident i
  left join wo_logs wl on
    i.ticketid = wl.origrecordid and
    wl.mxronsite = wl.min_mx
order by 1
```

Comment: I modified that to additionally select l.worklogid and wo.wonum as debugging tools. It's certainly close, but it still returns two work logs if one work order has two work logs with the same MXRONSITE.

Comment: This suffers the same problem, pulling through multiple records where there are different work orders or different work logs.

Unfortunately I'm out of time for this year, and will have to pick up on it in January. Thanks everyone for your help, I think this may be a case where I just have to import two tables and join them later in the process.